# How to return an array in Protobuf service rpc

Tags: protocol-buffers, rpc

I have the following schema in my `.proto` file:

```
service MyService {
    rpc GetItem (ItemQuery) returns (Item) {
    }
}

message ItemQuery {
    int id = 1;
}
message Item {
    int id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Now I want to add another rpc method to return multiple Items.
Something like this:

```
rpc GetItems (ItemsQuery) returns (repeated Item) {
}
```

Is there a better way to do it than define an Items message?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Option 1 - Use stream:

```
rpc GetItems (ItemsQuery) returns (stream Item) {
}
```

Option 2 - Set a response message which will use a repeated object:

```
service MyService {
    rpc GetItem (ItemQuery) returns (ItemResponse) {
    }
}

message ItemQuery {
    int id = 1;
}
message ItemResponse {
    repeated Item items = 1;
}
message Item {
    int id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Comment: I'm late for the party, but: Does option 2 have any advantages over option 1 or vice versa?

Comment: Option 1 is a stream, it means you are returning an iterator  and that means you can start processing the Items on client even before the server has finished sending all of them. Option 2 is a response object which contains a list of your Items. You can add some other properties to your ItemResponse (some metadata etc)...

Comment: Hi, Is there anyway we can return a key less array response as the response in gRPC? I tried stream, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Works wine with: ```message GetChannelsResponse {repeated string channel_name = 1;}```

Comment: Is there a way to return an array instead of an array wrapped by an object? i.e. [{},{}] instead of {[{}]}.